# Generic types and method declarations in Java Collections Framework

Tags: java, generics, collections, parameters, set

I have a question about the use of generic types in the Java Collections framework.

Here's a snippet of the `Set` interface taken from Oracle's Java Collections thread (found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)):

```
public interface Set<E> extends Collection<E> {
    // Basic operations
    int size();
    boolean isEmpty();
    boolean contains(Object element);
    // optional
    boolean add(E element);
    // optional
    boolean remove(Object element);
    ...
```

My question is this: Given that `Set<E>` is generic with generic type parameter `E`, why are the `contains` and `remove` methods declared to take arguments of type `Object`?  The `add` method takes an argument of type `E`, why don't `contains` and `remove` do the same?

Answer (score -1):

It is simply because of backwards compatibility to the time before generic where added to java.

This way old code still works.

Comment: Thanks, MrSmith42.  Do you have an example of the backwards compatibility in mind?  It would be nice to see it in action.